# Split a string into an array of paired numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to work out how to split the following hexadecimal string into an array of paired numbers.

At the moment i have the following:

```
function getRGB(hexVal) {

    var substrHexVal = hexVal.substring(1,hexVal.length);

    var splitHexVal = substrHexVal.split("");

    return splitHexVal;

}

var a = getRGB("#00FF00");

a;
```

Which returns the following:

```
["0", "0", "F", "F", "0", "0"]
```

But i need to get out this:

```
["00", "FF", "00"]
```

It is probably obvious what i am trying to do but i would like to do the rest myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to pass through the string, and separate the pairs with a comma. Finally split the string on the commas:

```
function getRGB(hexVal) {
  var commaSeperated = '';

  // Removes the first character from the input string
  hexVal = hexVal.substring(1, hexVal.length);

  // Now let's separate the pairs by a comma
  for (var i = 0; i < hexVal.length; i++) {
    // Iterate through each char of hexVal

    // Copy each char of hexVal to commaSeperated
    commaSeperated += hexVal.charAt(i);

    // After each pair of characters add a comma, unless this
    // is the last char
    commaSeperated += (i % 2 == 1 && i != (hexVal.length - 1)) ? ',' : '';
  }
  // split the commaSeperated string by commas and return the array
  return commaSeperated.split(',');
}

console.log(getRGB("#00FF00"));    //  ["00", "FF", "00"]
```

Comment: That's great.  Am a bit of a noob so would it be possible to aks for some comments?  :)

Comment: @ Daniel: Many thanks for the comments.  It helps so much more with understanding what is going on.

Answer (score 12):

Embrace the power of the functional side, Luke

```
a="#c0ffee"
"#c0ffee"

[1,3,5].map(function(o) {return a.slice(o,o+2)})
["c0", "ff", "ee"]
```

Comment: I like this version but am slightly unsure how it is working.  I understand that .map calls a provided function for each element in the array.  The array provided is 1,3,5 but i am not sure how the connection is made from there???

Comment: .map calls the anonymous function in parentheses for each member of the array [1,3,5].  Each time the function is called, o is equal to one of the array elements, and it also has access to the original variable a (hexVal in your version).  It calls a.slice with parameters o (start position) and o+2 (end position).  See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Answer (score 4):

```
function getRGB(hexVal) {

    return hexVal.toUpperCase().match(/[0-9A-F]{2}/g);

}
```

Take the string, convert it to uppercase, and extract all hexidecimal pairs with a simple regular expression.  The uppercase conversion isn't strictly necessary, but it ensures that your hex pairs are consistent.  You could just as easily make the alpha characters all lowercase (note that the "A-F" portion of a regex is now "a-f"):

```
function getRGB(hexVal) {

    return hexVal.toLowerCase().match(/[0-9a-f]{2}/g);

}
```

Or if you just don't care, then you can make your regex case insensitive, using the "i" modifier:

```
function getRGB(hexVal) {

    return hexVal.match(/[0-9a-f]{2}/gi);

}
```

Also, please note that none of these functions ensures that you get 3 pairs back.  If you pass "_?!@#$#00FF00FF" to it, you're going to get ["00", "FF", "00", "FF"].  Similarly, if you pass "00FF0", you'll get ["00", "FF"] because only 2 complete pairs are found.

In other words, you'll want to add some error-checking.

Answer (score 1):

```
function parseHexColor(colorVal) {
  var regex = /^#([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})$/i;
  colorVal = colorVal.replace(regex,"$1,$2,$3");
  return colorVal.split(",");
}
```

Obviously you'd want to test for bogus values, etc., and you could shorten it by a line, but this is a simple way to get what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the alternate answer.  I have no idea how i am going to ever get my head around this sort of stuff.  I just don't seem to think in the same way.

Comment: @Daniel Vassallo: IDK, someone's apparently in a bad mood. I'll return the favor.